# How do I save active tab after page refresh javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to save to active tab state on page refresh. Currently, I have the following code, however, when I output to console the ui-state-active it gives me back -1 as the value. And it doesn't seem to even register my click() function, cause my console.log in the function never outputs. I believe I am doing something wrong here.

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(".tabs").tabs();
            var tabIndex = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('activeTab')) + 1;
            console.log("local storage value parseInt: " + tabIndex);
            if(tabIndex != null){
                    console.log("I am in the if statement: " + localStorage.getItem('activeTab'));
                    $('.tabs > ul > li:nth-child('+ (tabIndex)  +')').find('a').click();
            }
        $(document).on("click", ".tab-links a", function(e) {
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            var curTab = $('.tab-links').find('.active')[0].id;
            console.log("This is the currentTab value: " + curTab.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' ));
            var curTabIndex = (curTab.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' ) - 1);
            localStorage.setItem('activeTab', curTabIndex);
        });
    </script>
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul class="tab-links">
            <li id="t1"><a href="#tab1" class="tab1a">One</a></li>
            <li id="t2"><a href="#tab2" class="tab2a">Two</a></li>
            <li id="t3"><a href="#tab3" class="tab3a">Three</a></li>
            <li id="t4"><a href="#tab4" class="tab4a">Four</a></li>
            <li id="t5"><a href="#tab5" class="tab5a">Five</a></li>
            <li id="t5"><a href="#tab6" class="tab6a">Six</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tab1" class="tab active" >
                <?php   include("tab_1.html");    ?>
            </div>

            <div id="tab2" class="tab" >
                <?php   include("tab_2.html");   ?>
            </div>

            <div id="tab3" class="tab" >
                <?php   include("tab_3.html");    ?>
            </div>

            <div id="tab4" class="tab active">
                <?php  include("tab_4.html"); ?>
            </div>

            <div id="tab5" class="tab active">
                <?php include("tab_5.html"); ?>
            </div>

            <div id="tab6" class="tab active">
                <?php include("tab_6.html") ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would recommend doing is inside your click handler, removing the 'active' class to begin with, then affixing it to the clicked element:

```js
$('.tab-links a').click(function(e) {
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  var curTab = $(this).parent()[0].id; // Or $('.tab-links').find('.active')[0].id;
  console.log("This is the currentTab value: " + curTab);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tab-links">
    <li id="t1"><a href="#tab1" class="tab1a">One</a></li>
    <li id="t2"><a href="#tab2" class="tab2a">Two</a></li>
    <li id="t3"><a href="#tab3" class="tab3a">Three</a></li>
    <li id="t4"><a href="#tab4" class="tab4a">Four</a></li>
    <li id="t5"><a href="#tab5" class="tab5a">Five</a></li>
    <li id="t5"><a href="#tab6" class="tab6a">Six</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab active"></div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab5" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab6" class="tab"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that you should only ever have one 'active' class at any one time.

Also be aware that if you are adding your elements dynamically, you will need to hoist the scope and utilise **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**. In this case, replace `$('.tab-links a').click(function(e) {})` with `$(document).on("click", ".tab-links a", function(e) {})`:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".tab-links a", function(e) {
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  var curTab = $(this).parent()[0].id; // Or $('.tab-links').find('.active')[0].id;
  console.log("This is the currentTab value: " + curTab);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tab-links">
    <li id="t1"><a href="#tab1" class="tab1a">One</a></li>
    <li id="t2"><a href="#tab2" class="tab2a">Two</a></li>
    <li id="t3"><a href="#tab3" class="tab3a">Three</a></li>
    <li id="t4"><a href="#tab4" class="tab4a">Four</a></li>
    <li id="t5"><a href="#tab5" class="tab5a">Five</a></li>
    <li id="t5"><a href="#tab6" class="tab6a">Six</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab active"></div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab5" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab6" class="tab"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: For some reason no matter what I do, it never reaches inside the click event function. It should output to console when I click right?

Comment: Are your elements dynamically created? In that case you need to **hoist the scope** and utilise [**event delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Try using `$(document).on("click", ".tab-links a", function(e) {})` instead of `$('.tab-links a').click(function(e) {})`.

Comment: If you update your code I will vote you the best answer.

Comment: @kkmoslehpour -- I've updated my answer to cover this, and I'm glad it fixed the problem for you. It's actually a common issue, and certainly something to watch for! ;)

Comment: Hey @Obsidian Age, I updated my code. I am having trouble on the last step. $('.tabs > ul > li:nth-child('+ (tabIndex)  +')').find('a').click(); This part doesn's seem to execute. Do I need to use even delegation here as well? I checked all my variables and everything seems to check out fine. But after i refresh the page, it doesn't seem to run the click() event.

Comment: You line if code above is sound, and will certainly work if the element already exists (assuming your localStorage is set and the variable is indeed returning an integer). Considering the element is **not** set, this is likely another case where you will need to use event delegation, this time in a far more complex way. Try replacing `$('.tabs > ul > li:nth-child('+ (tabIndex)  +')').find('a').click();` with `$(document).on("click", ".tabs > ul > li:nth-child(" + tabIndex + ")".find('a'), function(e) {})`.

Comment: Nope, that didn't seem to work. systemTest.php:89 Uncaught TypeError: ")".find is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/dhynozb5/2/

```js
$("#tabs").tabs();
var currentTab = $('.ui-state-active a').index();
if(localStorage.getItem('activeTab') != null){
  $('#tabs > ul > li:nth-child('+ (parseInt(localStorage.getItem('activeTab')) + 1)  +')').find('a').click();
}

 $('#tabs > ul > li > a').click(function(e) {
  var curTab = $('.ui-tabs-active');
  curTabIndex = curTab.index();
  localStorage.setItem('activeTab', curTabIndex);
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tab-links">
  <li id="t1"><a href="#tab1" class="tab1a">One</a></li>
  <li id="t2"><a href="#tab2" class="tab2a">Two</a></li>
  <li id="t3"><a href="#tab3" class="tab3a">Three</a></li>
  <li id="t4"><a href="#tab4" class="tab4a">Four</a></li>
  <li id="t5"><a href="#tab5" class="tab5a">Five</a></li>
  <li id="t5"><a href="#tab6" class="tab6a">Six</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab active" >
      tab_1.html
  </div>

  <div id="tab2" class="tab" >
     tab_2.html
  </div>

  <div id="tab3" class="tab" >
     tab_3.html
  </div>

  <div id="tab4" class="tab active">
    tab_4.html
  </div>

  <div id="tab5" class="tab active">
     tab_5.html
  </div>

  <div id="tab6" class="tab active">
     tab_6.html
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Highlighting an active tab after page refresh I've used `localStorage`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Even when I put a console.log () inside the click event, I am not seeing the output to log.

Comment: @kkmoslehpour... I didn't get you, what you are looking for?

Comment: It's weird that in your code it works, however, on my page it doesn't. Does it matter that this section of the html page is only a small part of my html page? Do I have to move the <script> higher so the scope is higher?

Comment: Also, my HTML is actually a .php file.

Comment: Also i notice that your currentTab = 0, while mine starts at -1.

Answer (score 0):

Either move your entire `<script></script>` block below the html or do the following:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tabs").tabs();
  var currentTab = $('.ui-state-active a').index();
  console.log("hi");
  console.log("this is the currentTab value: " + currentTab);
   $('.tablinks a').click(function(e) {
        console.log("i am in here");
        var curTab = $('.ui-tabs-active');
        curTabIndex = curTab.index();
        console.log(curTabIndex);
   });
});
</script>
```